# Error: Unable to initialize main class TEST_Automation.Test_1 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting below error when i am trying to execute below code

```java
package TEST_Automation;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Test_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class TEST_Automation.Test_1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

open chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by issues with the classpath or missing dependencies.

1. Check Selenium Dependency: Make sure you have added the Selenium WebDriver library to your project.
2. Correct Driver System Property: You have a small typo in the system property. It should be "webdriver.chrome.driver" instead of "Webdriver.chrome.driver".
3. Check Chromedriver Path: Make sure the path to the Chromedriver executable is correct. Also, ensure that the Chromedriver version matches your installed Chrome browser version.